# WPF Application : what controls for placing my user controls?

Tags: wpf, user-controls

i'm conceiving my app and want to take the good path at the beginning.

In my app, I will have a panel (say MainPanel), in which I'll have to display custom usercontrols I'll make  (say MainCustomControl).
MainCustomControl will be composed of other custom usercontrols (StepCustomControl, TransCustomControl, ActionCustomControl).

What I want is :
 - be able to place MainCustomControlsone above the others
 - in some row, i want to have many MainCustomControl
 - be able to insert a new MainCustomControl between two others

I tried a prototype with a DataGrid, but the result is inconclusive :
[First Prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3EJl.png)
What I want is something like that : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDjVb.png)

Is DataGrid adapted to my final goal ? If not, what should I use ?
If yes, I'll paste my current code to find why my MainCustomControl is not displayed as I wish. 
Also, should I make my own usercontrols to display the elements in MainCustomControl, or use another method ?

Comment: I plan to stock the associated class of MainCustomControl in an ObservableCollection<MyClass> : I will have to display all the content of this collection. Not sure if I answer your question ?

Comment: If i understand you correctly then this question is about layout? If so try using Grid. You can specify how many rows and columns the grid contains. Furthermore you can specify whether a control should span over multiple rows or columns by using RowSpan and ColumnSpan.

Comment: What about drag & dropping CustomControl with a grid ? I'll be able to do this, to move controls between them ? As i dont know by advance how many CustomControl i'll have per row, grid is still ok ?

Comment: yes, a grid is fine. You can drag and drop your Objects into the Grid and bind the row and column to the object.

Comment: So in my objects I&#39;ll have to create two property : one for the row, one for the column, and then bind this to the; xaml ?